# Time Series dataset preparation

Tags: time-series, regression, lstm, xgboost, forecasting

I am a bit confused with the time series dataset preparation. From the internet, I saw all examples which used tree-based models, had input features and target defined as:

```
X = df.drop(['target'], axis=1)
y = df["target"]
```

i.e. we use **input features and target of **the same timestamp** here**.

While using LSTM, say with a window of size x, we use input features of **all** x timestamps to predict the target value of **(x+1) th timestamp**. Suppose, if x was 1, i.e. window of size 1, we use **input features of just the ith time stamp to predict target value of the (i+1) th timestamp**.

While in tree based model, I end up using input features of ith time stamp to predict target value of same ith time stamp.

So should we shift the target column of tree based model by 1 and predict similar to what we do for LSTM?

Or what is the correct way to prepare the input dataset?